# Custom li value sort

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following script to start a custom sort, but it works with "category-class" and not with li value.

I was unsuccessful to modify this script, maybe someone can help me?

The script:

```
<ul id="input">
<li category="download">download</li>
<li category="video">video</li>
<li category="product">product</li>
<li category="any">any</li>
</ul>


(function($) {

$.fn.reOrder = function(array) {
  return this.each(function() {

    if (array) {    
      for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
        array[i] = $('li[category="' + array[i] + '"]');

      $(this).empty();  

      for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++)
        $(this).append(array[i]);      
    }
  });    
}
})(jQuery);

var category_sort_order = ['any', 'product', 'download', 'video'];
$('#input').reOrder(category_sort_order);
```

What I need (no category, just li value):

```
<ul id="input">
<li>download</li>
<li>video</li>
<li>product</li>
<li>any</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:**
Its important to me that I can ​​indicate the sort values (no alphabet sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for html you mentioned

```
<ul id="input">
<li>download</li>
<li>video</li>
<li>product</li>
<li>any</li>
</ul>
```

you can simply update your script to select li based on it's html instead of category like shown below

```
(function($) {

$.fn.reOrder = function(array) {
  return this.each(function() {

    if (array) {    
      for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
        array[i] = $('li:contains('+array[i]+')');

      $(this).empty();  

      for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++)
        $(this).append(array[i]);      
    }
  });    
}
})(jQuery);

var category_sort_order = ['any','product', 'download', 'video'];
$('#input').reOrder(category_sort_order);
```

that will work